# If Join Return NULL then do following

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have 3 tables

**Table1**

```
ID NAMEID OTHER
--------------------------------------
1  12345  BLAH
2  23456  BLAH
3  25896  BLAH
4  74896  BLAH
5  95124  BLAH
6  63258  BLAH
7  99999  BLAH
```

**Table2**

```
TID    Name
-------------------------------------
12345  Apple
23456  Orange
25896  Banana
74896  Grape
95124  Lime
63258  Berry
```

**Table3**

```
ID    Start_Date  End_Date Alt_Name
-------------------------------------
9999     BLAH       BLAH       Pears
12345    BLAH       BLAH             
23456    BLAH       BLAH       Orange
```

**Relations**

```
 Table1.NAMEID = Table2.TID
 Table1.ID     = Table3.ID
```

Sometimes NameID won't be found in Table2.TID
so if it is not found in table2 then find table3.

**Here is Query and Current result**

```
Select 
      Table1.ID
      Table2.Name
      Table3.Start_Date
      Table3.End_Date
      Table1.Other
from Table1 Table1
left outer join Table3 Table3 ON Table1.ID     = Table3.ID
left outer join Table2 Table2 On Table1.NAMEID = Table2.TID
```

**Current - Output**

```
ID    Name    Start_Date  End_Date    Other
-------------------------------------------
1     Apple      Blah       Blah       Blah
2     Orange     Blah       Blah       Blah
3     Banana     Blah       Blah       Blah
4     Grape      Blah       Blah       Blah
5     Lime       Blah       Blah       Blah
6     Berry      Blah       Blah       Blah
7      NULL      Blah       Blah       Blah
```

**Output I want**

```
ID    Name    Start_Date  End_Date    Other
-------------------------------------------
1     Apple      Blah       Blah       Blah
2     Orange     Blah       Blah       Blah
3     Banana     Blah       Blah       Blah
4     Grape      Blah       Blah       Blah
5     Lime       Blah       Blah       Blah
6     Berry      Blah       Blah       Blah
7     Pears      Blah       Blah       Blah
```

In table 3
For each ID Alt_Name is not always there, it is null too sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        COALESCE(b.Name, c.AltName, '-no name-') as `Name`
        c.Start_DATE,
        c.End_DATE,
        a.Other
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN table2 b
            ON a.nameID = b.tid
        LEFT JOIN table3 c
            ON a.NameID = c.ID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was very simple solution :)

Comment: I had never understood what Coalesce did but now I do thanks to you.

Comment: @Mowgli COALESCE returns the first non null value passed as parameter, eg, `SELECT COALESCE(null, 'aaa','bbb')`. the query will return `aaa` since it is the first nonnull value on the list.